# Is there any public documentation of the LapLink protocol?

Tags: ms-dos, network, serial, reference-request

Is the protocol used by the DOS [Laplink](https://winworldpc.com/product/laplink/5x) software publicly documented?

I seem to remember there were Linux tools that could use it.

I cannot find anything useful on [their website](https://help.laplink.com/).

Comment: Are you sure it is the laplink protocol or was it just the laplink cable?

Comment: Probably just the name https://tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Serial-Laplink-HOWTO.pdf

Comment: [This](http://minuszerodegrees.net/laplink/laplink.htm) suggests that different versions of Laplink used different protocols, and the timing seems to depend on system speed. One way to find out would be to reverse-engineer the Laplink binary.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I’m aware, it isn’t.

I don’t remember any Linux software capable of connecting to LapLink; the latter was commonly mentioned because the cable provided with it could be used with a variety of tools. DOS-to-Linux connections with null-modem cables usually involved PLIP, SLIP or [PPPD](http://www.resoo.org/docs/dos/free_software/comm2.htm#dospppd) rather than LapLink-style tools.

Comment: Laplink was (ab)using the parallel port  for standard higher speeds afair.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro PLIP does the same, but unfortunately not in the same way.